# Adding visuals to a VS C++ console program

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, graphics

Apologies for the stupid question, but I'm just too confused with all the options for adding graphics to a program.

I'm a novice C++ programmer (Windows only) and I've made a console program in Visual Studio that processes a lot of data. The results are becoming somewhat difficult to review in text form. I want to add some graphical representations, not statistical graphs, but more like symbolical representations, lines, circles, that visualize the structure of the data. I have no use for OpenGL functionality, no need for mathematical graphs, no need for menus, checkboxes and the like. I just want to draw some lines on the screen.

How do I make that step from console text-only to drawing something? A book like the C++ Primer contains not a single word on graphics of any kind. You learn about copy constructors and templates and then you want to draw a pixel on screen and suddenly you're left on your own in a wilderness of endless third-party libraries and godknowswhat. And it's really unclear how do all of these things affect performance, will my purely data-processing program be suddenly straddled with some huge framework that contains tons of functionality that I do not need.

The topic on C++ books on this site contains *one* book that seems it might include something on graphics, API Design for C++. That's it. I'm a book-reading guy, I really want to study an issue comprehensively rather than dig through forums and deal with a hundred different and possibly biased opinions (like, "use MFC!" - "MFC is dead!"). Does such a book/manual/tutorial exist? Would the "API Design for C++" be it, perhaps?
(I looked for similar questions here, but none of them have good answers; in one of them the asker was advised to learn C#).

Edit: The "API Design for C++" is about something else entirely, so that makes 0 books about a graphical interface of any kind on the C++ books list on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ standard defines absolutely no pixel-based graphics output functionality. The reason is that graphic output is highly operating-system dependent. Every operating system defines its own API for graphic output. That means when you want graphics, you won't get around using a library.

You could either learn the native graphic API of your favorite operating system (On Windows, that would be [WinAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee663266.aspx)), or you could use a library which abstracts graphic output in an operating-system independent way. For 2d graphics I can recommend [SFML (Simple Fast Multimedia Library)](http://www.sfml-dev.org/).

Comment: So is the "Definitive C++ Book Guide and List" on this site limited to books that don't cover anything besides what's in the standard? I'm sure that's not the case, yet nothing on graphics?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  There's gotten to be this attitude that a programming language consists only of the abstract, formal elements that are in the language definition.  So a book on learning or using C++ *in the context of doing the sort of stuff PC programmers want make their PCs do* isn't "a C++ book."  Older books are better for this -- if you bought a C book in the 1980s the chances are good it would teach you about "setpixel" and "getkey" functions -- but now "C language texts" are all about The Standard ANSI C Language Abstraction and talk about "undefined behavior" and "sequence points."

Comment: @user3101050 I am sure there is plenty of literature covering specific graphic APIs. You just have to search by the API name and not by the programming language. But I couldn't suggest any because I am more of a online reference guy.

Answer (score 1):

Visual C++ comes with several libraries and can build a skeletal sample application for all of them. I suggest you try them all. Any recent book on Visual C++ will help you survey some possibilities.

The main impediment to your wishes is that for graphical output you have to change the entire structure of your program. It must respond to Windows messages (like WM_PAINT) and a console program is not oriented toward processing messages.

Comment: I only need the graphical output once the actual data-processing has finished. I don't suppose it's possible to "switch" from console to GUI at a specific point in the program?

Comment: Yes, that is certainly possible. There are several Win32 tutorials on the net for the bare basics with no extra library needed. Your console program can "switch" to GUI by calling CreateWindow, then running a message loop, and handling the messages that arrive in the windowProc. Handle WM_PAINT and you will be in business.

Answer (score 0):

The Boost library has been successful in introducing things that have become part of the C++ standard, like `shared_ptr`.

Why not try the [Boost Generic Image Library (GIL)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html).

Disclaimer: I have only looked at it, but since it's not unlikely to become part of the C++ standard (possibly like the C standard, "incorporated") I plan to try it out.

---

To get an image *presented*, I think the easiest is to just save it as a file, then invoke the default viewer for that file type ‐ which might even be possible to do via the C++ standard `system` function.

Comment: This would be great if the most "accessible" documentation for it wouldn't start out straight away with advanced generic programming.

Answer (score -1):

Why there is no graphics in C++ has nothing to do with the programming language and everything to do with monopolistic business reasons. In fact, C++ Version 3.0 from Borland circa 1992 had a graphics.h and graphics.o facility that allowed precisely to do what the user asks.

My statement above is supported by evidence:  How come, from C/C++ we could print any graphic image we want on printers going way back to black and white devices?  Answer: The ASCII character set was developed before any monopoly could block it and printer manufacturers published the required escape sequences to send pixels to their printers.  Also, CGA graphics in the IBM PC was memory mapped.  Users could develop in C/C++ real-time graphics like Flight Simulator, Pinball Machine, Chess and Golf without having to use a vendor library.

What we need now is an ISO extension (using escape sequences) to the character encoding standards that permits to define pixel addressing withing a character cell.  In that way, the graphics capability is seamlessly extended into the existing character oriented console systems.  This could be added to the C/C++ standards.  Of course, such action would break the grip the GUI exerts on would-be-competitors of current operating system vendors! In fact, it would also be necessary for the operating system vendor to allow the user to access the device in its native context, something we have already seen as deprecated by a vendor--one should investigate some of the complaints about Windows Vista.

So there is your reason and also my suggestion about what we (the public at large) collectively should ask the standard organizations to do.  After all C/C++ with its portability strategy was supposed to break the monopoly stronghold created by vendors who wanted to control the developmental agenda of their computer languages (JAVA and PL/1 come to mind as examples).